# how to fill background color of nav element

Tags: html, colors, nav

I want my  element to have a background color fill, I tried the following but it didn't work, how can I apply a color fill to it? Thanks

```
<nav id="Nav" bgcolor="#000000">
        <a href="index.html">Home</a> |
        <a href="Gallery.html">Library</a> |
        <a href="Contact.html">Contact</a> |
        <a href="About.html">About</a>
</nav>
```

Comment: To make sense of the answers already given here, I recommend you read up on CSS; old-style attribute soup (bgcolor et al) is long-deprecated and well worth unlearning.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
<nav id="Nav" style="background:#000000;">
    <a href="index.html">Home</a> |
    <a href="Gallery.html">Library</a> |
    <a href="Contact.html">Contact</a> |
    <a href="About.html">About</a>
</nav>
```

Comment: Use css to style it instead because bgcolor is used to style the <body> and it is not supported in HTML5.